# By substitution or otherwise verify that the circular path satisfies the equation

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, functions, differential-geometry

A beam of light travelling between the points (0, $y_0$) and $(x_1, y_1)$ in the (x, y) plane will travel
along the curve y(x) where y' = dy/dx.

I have worked out that the path y(x) must satisfy the equation

$$y\sqrt{1+y'^2}=\frac{1}{c}$$

the beam of light is travelling within the infinitely wide strip between y=$y_0$ and y=$2y_0$ where $y_0$>0

By substitution or otherwise, I must
verify that the circular path satisfies my previous equation.

$y(x)^2+ (x-x_0)^2=\frac{1}{c^2}$

I have tried making the equations equal each other but that has come up blank I think I have to find y'(x) when I try to differentiate y(x) all I get is y'(x)=-1 and that doesn't help very much either. all help would be greatly appreciated as this question has me really stumped. feel free to adapt tags as you see fit I wasn't sure what to put for this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square the first equation and set it equal to the second
$$y^2+ (x-x_0)^2=y^2(1+(y')^2   ) 
\\[9pt]   \iff(x-x_0)^2 = (yy')^2$$
Now implicitly differentiate the second equation

$$2yy' +2(x-x_0) = 0  \iff yy'=-(x-x_0)  $$

Comment: $y$ is the name of a function of $x$, $y(x)$ and $y$ mean the same thing.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up for me